# How does one use an NSTimer to update a label for elapsed time in minutes and seconds?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have the timer counting down but I'm having trouble with:

1. Getting the timer to start over continuously once it hits 0
2. Having the countdown like this: 4:00, 3:59, 3:58... rather than 240, 239, 238...

Here is my code:

```
ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var incomeTimeLabel: UILabel!
    var timer: NSTimer!
    let startIncomeTime = 240
    var incomeTime = 240

    func startTimer() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, 
                    selector: #selector(ViewController.timerStarted),
                    userInfo: nil, repeats:  true)
    }

    func timerStarted() {
        incomeTimer()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTimer()
    }

    func incomeTimer() {
        if incomeTime > -1 {
            incomeTimeLabel.text = String(incomeTime--)
        } else if incomeTime == -1 {
            incomeTimeLabel.text = String(startIncomeTime)
        }
    }
}
```

Ive been teaching myself to code for only a few months but I feel like theres a more efficient way to do this, so any other advice you think would help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seems to be missing something in your posted code. Where do you set the timer?

Comment: The startTimer() function. Ill add more to make that more clear. Sorry bout that

Comment: @NelsonJ I edited your code snippet. Please be sure to look at what I did, especially regarding organization and formatting, and learn from it. Welcome to SO! Be sure to participate and vote/check correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what an `NSTimer` is. It's not a "timer" like a stopwatch. It provides a means for executing a method asynchronously at certain intervals (eg. "call this method every 1 second").

While the following is a little overkill, it uses MVC to illustrate the point. Code example taken from the ["Teaching App Development with Swift" Stopwatch project](https://swifteducation.github.io/teaching_app_development_with_swift/stopwatch.html).

Model **Stopwatch.swift**:

```
import Foundation

class Stopwatch {

    private var startTime: NSDate?

    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval {
        if let startTime = self.startTime {
            return -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    var elapsedTimeAsString: String {
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d.%d",
            Int(elapsedTime / 60),
            Int(elapsedTime % 60),
            Int(elapsedTime * 10 % 10))
    }

    var isRunning: Bool {
        return startTime != nil
    }

    func start() {
        startTime = NSDate()
    }

    func stop() {
        startTime = nil
    }

}
```

Controller **ViewController.swift**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var elapsedTimeLabel: UILabel!
    let stopwatch = Stopwatch()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func startStopwatch(sender: UIButton) {
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self,
            selector: "updateElapsedTimeLabel:", userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)
        stopwatch.start()
    }

    @IBAction func stopStopwatch(sender: UIButton) {
        stopwatch.stop()
    }

    func updateElapsedTimeLabel(timer: NSTimer) {
        if stopwatch.isRunning {
            elapsedTimeLabel.text = stopwatch.elapsedTimeAsString
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

}
```

In other words, you need to do your "time math" with `NSDate` objects, not `Int`s.

To obtain feature #1 you mention in your question, you could change the logic in `updateElapsedTimeLabel:` to call a function when the difference between the `stopwatch.elapsedTime` and an `NSDate` "four minutes from now" is 0.

To obtain feature #2, of counting down, simply add a method `timeLeft` that returns the difference between an `NSDate` "four minutes from now" and the elapsedTime.

The point here is to understand how `NSTimer` works, how to use `NSDate` to calculate the difference between two moments in time, and how to use format strings to display what you want. There's enough raw material here for you to implement your own requirements.

Comment: The idea is I want something to happen when it hits 0, but I want to see the countdown until that point if that makes sense. So wouldn't an NSTimer be the right way to do that?

Comment: @NelsonJ, Be sure to read my answer carefully, you seem to be missing out on the point entirely.

Comment: @NelsonJ You should [read the class docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimer) for `NSTimer` .